# Why is the java.exe is consuming more CPU due to "EnhancedQueueExecutor.java" threads?

Tags: web-applications, java-8, thread-dump, wildfly-12

I am running WildFly 12 with JDK 1.8 version. We faced the slowness issue due to high CPU usage of java.exe. Then, we have taken a thread dump using JStack and most of the high CPU threads are pointing to **at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1422)**

Below is the thread dump error trace:

```
"default task-53" #378 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000003179a800 nid=0x3c0 waiting on condition [0x000000004eabf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000665d6b8f0> (a org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1422)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Recently we have upgraded to WildFly 12 from WildFly 9(JDK 1.7). Post that, we are facing this type of issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That particular thread is not consuming any CPU. Besides that, it’s not surprising that threads of an executor do lots of work. That’s why they are often called *worker threads*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Holger. It is consuming 50% of CPU, whenever the portal goes down / slow. Is there any way to control the high CPU on this thread?

Comment: You have to identify the actual method the threads consuming CPU time are in. The `run` method is common to all threads. The interesting methods are the ones invoked from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Holger. Let me check the actual cause for high CPU.